# How to compare an element of a tuple (int) to determine if it exists in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, comparison, tuples

I have the two following lists:

```
# List of tuples representing the index of resources and their unique properties
#    Format of (ID,Name,Prefix)
resource_types=[('0','Group','0'),('1','User','1'),('2','Filter','2'),('3','Agent','3'),('4','Asset','4'),('5','Rule','5'),('6','KBase','6'),('7','Case','7'),('8','Note','8'),('9','Report','9'),('10','ArchivedReport',':'),('11','Scheduled Task',';'),('12','Profile','<'),('13','User Shared Accessible Group','='),('14','User Accessible Group','>'),('15','Database Table Schema','?'),('16','Unassigned Resources Group','@'),('17','File','A'),('18','Snapshot','B'),('19','Data Monitor','C'),('20','Viewer Configuration','D'),('21','Instrument','E'),('22','Dashboard','F'),('23','Destination','G'),('24','Active List','H'),('25','Virtual Root','I'),('26','Vulnerability','J'),('27','Search Group','K'),('28','Pattern','L'),('29','Zone','M'),('30','Asset Range','N'),('31','Asset Category','O'),('32','Partition','P'),('33','Active Channel','Q'),('34','Stage','R'),('35','Customer','S'),('36','Field','T'),('37','Field Set','U'),('38','Scanned Report','V'),('39','Location','W'),('40','Network','X'),('41','Focused Report','Y'),('42','Escalation Level','Z'),('43','Query','['),('44','Report Template ','\\'),('45','Session List',']'),('46','Trend','^'),('47','Package','_'),('48','RESERVED','`'),('49','PROJECT_TEMPLATE','a'),('50','Attachments','b'),('51','Query Viewer','c'),('52','Use Case','d'),('53','Integration Configuration','e'),('54','Integration Command f'),('55','Integration Target','g'),('56','Actor','h'),('57','Category Model','i'),('58','Permission','j')]

# This is a list of resource ID's that we do not want to reference directly, ever.
unwanted_resource_types=[0,1,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,20,21,23,25,27,28,32,35,38,41,47,48,49,50,57,58]
```

I'm attempting to compare the two in order to build a third list containing the 'Name' of each unique resource type that currently exists in `unwanted_resource_types`. e.g. The final result list should be: 
`result = ['Group','User','Agent','ArchivedReport','ScheduledTask','...','...']`

I've tried the following that (I thought) should work:

```
result = []
for res in resource_types:
    if res[0] in unwanted_resource_types:
        result.append(res[1])
```

and when that failed to populate `result` I also tried:

```
result = []
for res in resource_types:
    for type in unwanted_resource_types:
        if res[0] == type:
            result.append(res[1])
```

also to no avail. Is there something i'm missing? I believe this would be the right place to perform list comprehension, but that's still in my grey basket of understanding fully (The Python docs are a bit too succinct for me in this case).

I'm also open to completely rethinking this problem, but I do need to retain the list of tuples as it's used elsewhere in the script. Thank you for any assistance you may provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your resource types are using strings, and your unwanted resources are using ints, so you'll need to do some conversion to make it work.

Try this:

```
result = []
for res in resource_types:
    if int(res[0]) in unwanted_resource_types:
        result.append(res[1])
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
result = [item[1] for item in resource_types if int(item[0]) in unwanted_resource_types]
```

Comment: Thank you! This will work like a charm. Instead of converting res[0] at runtime, i'm going to convert the first element in each tuple to an int so the code looks better, but I still would like to go through that list comprehension you wrote out.

Comment: @EthanFurman Those 2 code snippets give the opposite results, so clearly one of them _is_ wrong.

Comment: How embarassing -- fixed the first one.  (I had thought hochl was referring to the second one.)

Comment: @EthanFurman I think hochl was referring to the second one.  If you look at the question, the expected results are `['Group','User','Agent',...]`.  Using `not in` gives `['Filter', 'Asset', 'Rule', 'KBase'...]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your triples contain strings and your unwanted resources contain numbers, change the data to

```
resource_types=[(0,'Group','0'), ...
```

or use `int()` to convert the strings to ints before comparison, and it should work. Your result can be computed with a list comprehension as in

```
result=[rt[1] for rt in resource_types if int(rt[0]) in unwanted_resource_types]
```

If you change `('0', ...)` into `(0, ...` you can leave out the `int()` call.

Additionally, you may change the `unwanted_resource_types` variable into a `set`, like

```
unwanted_resource_types=set([0,1,3, ... ])
```

to improve speed (if speed is an issue, else it's unimportant).

Comment: Great. I intend to convert the first element in that tuples to int for code sanity reasons. Even if it doesn't really matter as I doubt execution time will change, I will convert the list of ints to a set, more speed is better right? ;) I'm also trying to ingrain "best practices" into my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in `resource_types` are numbers contained within strings, whereas the numbers in `unwanted_resource_types` are plain numbers, so your comparison is failing.  This should work:

```
result = []
for res in resource_types:
    if int( res[0] ) in unwanted_resource_types:
        result.append(res[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner:

```
result = map(lambda x: dict(map(lambda a: (int(a[0]), a[1]), resource_types))[x], unwanted_resource_types)
```

without any explicit loop does the job.

Ok - you don't want to use this in production code - but it's fun. ;-)

Comment:
The inner *dict(map(lambda a: (int(a[0]), a[1]), resource_types))* creates a dictionary from the input data:

```
{0: 'Group', 1: 'User', 2: 'Filter', 3: 'Agent', ...
```

The outer map chooses the names from the dictionary.

Comment: I like this. Not going to use it, but I like it :)

Comment: Noone will ever debug this :-)